# NSTask for SSH using PTY

Tags: objective-c, ssh, nstask, pty

I'm trying to write an app that will programmatically log in to a remote device using SSH much like an expect script (I know I can use expect but I would like to do this in Obj-c).

I have researched a lot on this and know that I need to use a pty.  The code I have works fine for telnet but I can't seem to get ssh to work.  It seems as though SSH is not using the pty to ask for the password.  When I execute the following code I see the device asking for the password, but I don't see my NSLog output.

I'm very new to this and probably over my head, but I'd really appreciate anyone who can help me get this working.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <util.h>

@interface NSTask (PTY)

- (NSFileHandle *)masterSideOfPTYOrError:(NSError **)error;

@end

@implementation NSTask (PTY)

- (NSFileHandle *)masterSideOfPTYOrError:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {
int fdMaster, fdSlave;
int rc = openpty(&fdMaster, &fdSlave, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (rc != 0) {
    if (error) {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSPOSIXErrorDomain code:errno userInfo:nil];
    }
    return NULL;
}
fcntl(fdMaster, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
fcntl(fdSlave, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
NSFileHandle *masterHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fdMaster closeOnDealloc:YES];
NSFileHandle *slaveHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fdSlave closeOnDealloc:YES];
self.standardInput = slaveHandle;
self.standardOutput = slaveHandle;
return masterHandle;
}

@end
```

---

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/ssh"];

    [task setArguments:@[@"user@192.168.1.1"]];

    NSError *error;
    NSFileHandle *masterHandle = [task masterSideOfPTYOrError:&error];
    if (!masterHandle) {
        NSLog(@"error: could not set up PTY for task: %@", error);
        exit(0);
    }

    [task launch];

    [masterHandle waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
    NSMutableString *buff = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification
                                                      object:masterHandle queue:nil
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
     {
         NSData *outData = [masterHandle availableData];
         NSString *outStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:outData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         [buff appendString:outStr];
         NSLog(@"output: %@", outStr);

         NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"sername:"
                                                                                options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                  error:nil];
         NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:buff
                                                         options:0
                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [buff length])];
         if (match) {
             NSLog(@"got a match!!");
             [buff setString:@""];
             [masterHandle writeData:[@"bhughes\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
         }

         NSLog(@"Exiting function.\n");
         [masterHandle waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
     }];

    [task waitUntilExit];

    NSLog(@"Program complete.\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `NSTask` does not support `pty` ability. Working with something like `ssh` requires interactive pty device context.

The simplest way to do this is [`forkpty`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/forkpty.3.html), but this forks process itself, so it cannot be used with `NSTask`.

Finally I wrote a wrapper class that manages `forkpty`. That forks a child process and calls `forkpty` and `execve`.

Here's my implementation: https://github.com/eonil/PseudoTeletypewriter.Swift

You can read/write using single master device file handle.
I confirmed that `sudo` is working, and I believe `ssh` also should work fine.

Comment: Is it possible you update it for Swift 3.0 as it is supposed to be stable and future releases will be backwards compatible?